# GAE low-level Java Datastore API

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Where do I use the Google App Engine low-level Java Datastore API?
In the frontend or in the Backend?
I just dont get it still after 10 hours reading around... I am just too stupid.

An example or a tutorial would be awesome...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The low-level Java Datastore API is for managing your data (Add, Modify, Delete and Search) with simple operations on entities, including get, put, delete, and query

The data is typically managed in the Backend code (via Java classes) and it works with the Datastore, which is a non-relational datastore. So if this is your first time with non-relational stuff, it will take a bit of time to get used to it.

To begin understanding the API, check out the Guestbook Application and how the [Datastore API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/usingdatastore) is used over there. Additionally, there is a good tutorial [here](http://googcloudlabs.appspot.com/codelabexercise1.html).

Keep in mind, that there are various other options available too for working with the Datastore other than the low level API. You could use the JDO or JPA implementations available with the App Engine SDK to model and persist your data.

There are also excellent libraries like [Objectify](https://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/) that make your task much simpler.

Comment: Hey, thank you for the fast answer.
I just need a query for a project and I need it really fast. 
I did the tutorials already, also the webshop tutorial and guestbook etc.! I still don't get it, sorry. I actually don't care if it is JDO or JPA or whatever. So far I just used the functions that are automatically created in the -Endpoint class.
Could you please explain me shortly:
So I create a new Class in the "-App Engine" project. 
how does this class look like then?
I just want a function:
     getArticle(String name){
         doquery();
         return article;
     }

Thank you...

Comment: Difficult to answer without seeing more of your code. Sorry for the plugin, but I have written a series of tutorial on Endpoints which include auto generation of the Datastore code from your Java class (for e.g. Article class). Check Part 2 specifically : http://rominirani.com/2014/01/13/google-cloud-endpoints-tutorial-part-2/

Comment: Thank you, looks nice.
But I dont need to just modify a little code, a need a whole new function:
Is it implemented like this?
`code`
@ApiMethod(name = "getcertainArticle")
public Article getcertainArticle(String name) {
}
`code`

Thanks

Comment: Hey, I did it, thank you.
Can you tell me one more thing: How can I create an auto generated long Id when inserting an entity? Nothing seems to work. I always get 503 Error.